# login page with local storage in vue.js

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, local-storage, vue-router

I want to create a login page which calls the sample login API(https://reqres.in/).

I want after user logged in it go to another page and users stay logged in if the page is
refreshed but after i click the login button it doesn't go to another page and just login page refresh! and local storage is empty.

thank you for your help!

this is my login form:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input required v-model="email" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" required v-model="password" />
    <button @click="login">LOGIN</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      let result = await axios.get(
        `https://reqres.in/api/users?email=${this.email}&password=${this.password}`
      );
      if (result.status == 200 && result.data.length > 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(result.data));
        this.$router.push("/firstPage");
      }
      console.log(result)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `<form>` contains a single `<button>`, it's treated as the form's submit button, causing the `submit` event, which reloads the page.

To solve this, you can invoke `Event.preventDefault` on the form's `submit`-event with the `v-on:submit` directive along with the [`.prevent` event modifier](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on):

```html
<form @submit.prevent>
  ⋮
</form>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-prevent-form-submit?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.vue)

Comment: thanks.my code problem is in two part :1-<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">.2-&& result.data.length > 0 . for the second problem i don't know why it's make an error that nothing save in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Named Routes: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

There is a full example here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/named-routes/app.js

Comment: thanks.I try it ways but it doesn't work. login page refresh and local storage is empty

Comment: Ok. Then you can try using "@click.prevent.stop="login()" on the button.

Comment: answer is <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"></form> not adding to button